# How to send a message from an end device to multiple application servers in LoRaWAN?

Tags: arduino, iot, lora, lorawan

I am trying to understand how I can send a message from an end-device to more than one LoRaWalAN application server? Do messages reach the application servers by addressing AppEUI? If so, can we set more than one APPEUI as destination for LoRa end-devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I could get a reply from  [the things network forum](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/forum/t/how-to-send-a-message-from-end-device-to-multiple-application-server-in-lorawan/41363) . The reply is that it is not possible. An end device can only be active in one LoRaWAN network and that network will only process the message on one application server. Once it gets to the application server multiple other servers could subscribe to the data feed using MQTT

Answer (score 0):

AppEUI is not addressing an Application Server. AppEUI is addressing the JoinServer of the device. If the applied Network Server is not connected to any external Join Server, the AppEUI is not used for Join Server selection at all. In that case all Join Requests are answered by the default, embedded Join Server.
In the LoRaWAN1.1 spec the confusing name: AppEUI has been renamed to JoinEUI.

A LoRaWAN end device can communicate to several Application Servers. The message routing between the end device and Application Servers is done based on the FPort of the LoRaWAN uplink message. For example you can set on the NS that FPort=100 is routed to AS1 and FPort=101 is routed to AS2. It is also possible that the NS sends messages simultaneously to several AS. All these routing options are supported by Actility's ThingPark NS.